# Authentication and Authorization in Asp.net MVC 4 web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I know how to use Authorization and Authentication attributes in asp.Net webform applications but I need to upgrade my old website to MVC 4, and I am new to this and don't know how it works here.

I tried to use it globally in web.config file but it is not helping me.
I used `[Authorize]` attribute on the contents which I want to hide from anonymous users and used `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to allow access to anonymous users.
Also, I enable **Authentication** in `web.config` file but still I am not getting any desired result from that.
As, soon as I apply `[Authorize]` attribute on any of the Page it simply not allow even the authenticated users.
Any help will be appreciated.
I used following code;

in **Global.asax** file:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new LogonAuthorize());
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute());
    filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
}
```

And for example I want to disallow anonymous user to access my home page, I used;

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

On **Login page** I used

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```

In web.config file I used

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
 </authentication>
 <authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
 </authorization>
```

But I got the same problem as I mentioned earlier. Any help with a bit explanation will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have multiple global Authorization filters, and you're using Authorize decorated classes as well.  What is `LogonAuthorize()`?

If you're going to use a global AuthorizeAttribute filter, then don't use Authorize on your classes, and only use AllowAnonymous on methods you want anonymous users to access.

Remove any authorization elements from web.config.  Leave the Authentication element.

(just noticed, this is 6 months old... I doubt you're still looking)